# How to restrict user to type 10 digit numbers in input element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a input field for phone number.  I am creating input field using JavaScript dynamically.

```
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
```

How to restrict users to type only 10 digit numbers in order to get a phone number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [validating 10 characters, can only be numbers, then redirecting to a web address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011291/validating-10-characters-can-only-be-numbers-then-redirecting-to-a-web-address)

Comment: @Hariharan `size` doesn’t restrict the input field.

Comment: maxlength should be used.

Comment: I have validation code in jquery but its not working because I have used javascript to create input text field.

Comment: If this is created using JavaScript, then it is natural, and rather trivial, to do the checking with JavaScript. What have you tried? The difficult part is what to do (and which message to issue) when the input is not acceptable. On the other hand, it is a good principle to accept at least spaces, too, in phone number input.

Comment: My phone number is 0033 5 61 ** ** **. 13 digits including the country code. How would you handle people from different countries, or are they just not able to use your form?

Comment: Right now, it is for only country, I will modify it later for more than one.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try this

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" title="Error Message" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}">
```

This will ensure

1. It is numeric
2. It will be max of 10 chars
3. First digit is not zero

Comment: it is not working when the type is not "text", maybe that's the issue

Comment: It works AWESOME but here in Australia numbers start from '0'...
@Wenuka how can I make the above element accept first digit be a '0'?

Comment: maybe try this pattern "[0]{1}[0-9]{9}"

Comment: yes, [0]{1}[0-9]{9} is fine. Use an online "regex online tester" to check whether your regular expression is working fine.

Comment: hey @Wenuka and Vinay, `[1]{1}[0-9]{9}` would be fine for 10 digits.. what would it be if I needed it to be of **at least** `n` length, should I use an asterisk like `[1]{1}[0-9]{n-1}[0-9]{*}`?

Answer (score 15):

Use `maxlength`

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: Edited attribute value to the one requested in the question.

Comment: In this case Input field would accept text, i.e any string of max length 10 would be accepted. - @NiettheDarkAbsol

Answer (score 12):

You can use `maxlength` to limit the length. Normally for numeric input you'd use `type="number"`, however this adds a spinny box thing to scroll through numbers, which is completely useless for phone numbers. You can, however, use the `pattern` attribute to limit input to numbers (and require 10 numbers too, if you want):

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" pattern="\d{10}" title="Please enter exactly 10 digits" />
```

Comment: Okay I will try this but I have solved my problem, I also posted my own answer too.

Comment: What browser are you using? Old versions of IE don't support it. Then again it shouldn't matter, because all validation should be server-side anyway.

Comment: If you mean that it still lets you type non-numeric characters, then that's normal. It's non-invasive, in that it lets the user type what they want, and informing them inline when they enter invalid data. You should never block the user from typing what they want. For instance, that's why YouTube comments (and even comments here) will just tell you how many characters over the limit you are, instead of just preventing you from typing. That way, you can type out what you mean in full, and then work on shortening it to fit.

Comment: [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RXVvx/), and [my result](http://prntscr.com/1y3w31) when tying in a non-numeric value and clicking the Submit button.

Comment: type="text" then this will allow alphabets aslo. who needs alphabets in phone number

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla "You can, however, use the `pattern` attribute to limit input to numbers"

Answer (score 5):

Well I have successfully created my own working answer.

```
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" onkeypress="phoneno()" maxlength="10">
```

as well as

```
    <script>        
           function phoneno(){          
            $('#phone').keypress(function(e) {
                var a = [];
                var k = e.which;

                for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
                    a.push(i);

                if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))
                    e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
       </script>
```

Comment: This code does not restrict user for alphabetic input.

Comment: Well, If it doesn't restrict alphabetic input then it's pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `maxlength` attribute to your input.

```
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="10">
```

See this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/43Rmm/) on JSFiddle.

Comment: size determines width, it doesn’t restrict anything.

Comment: My apologies, I was meant to write maxlength. Answer has been revised.

Comment: this will allow to enter 'abcdc' in textbox who needs number in phonenumber

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="fieldName" id="fieldSelectorId">
```

This field only takes at max 10 digits number and do n't accept zero as the first digit.

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery("#fieldSelectorId").keypress(function (e) {
         var length = jQuery(this).val().length;
       if(length > 9) {
            return false;
       } else if(e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            return false;
       } else if((length == 0) && (e.which == 48)) {
            return false;
       }
      });
    });
```

Comment: please change the text datatype to number datatype

Answer (score 1):

use a maxlength attribute to your input.

```
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="10">
```

See the fiddle demo here [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/w5A38/)

Comment: change the code : "text" datatype  to "number" datatype

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('keypress','#typeyourid',function(e){
if($(e.target).prop('value').length>=10){
if(e.keyCode!=32)
{return false} 
}})
```

Advantage is this works with type="number"

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
<input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" title="Please use a 10 digit telephone number with no dashes or dots" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required /> <i>10 digits</i>
```

It clarifies exactly what is expected in the entry and gives usable error messages.

Answer (score 0):

whereas you could use **maxLength** on the input, and some **javascript validation**, it will still be necessary to do **server side validation** anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="youridher" size="10">
```

Use **JQuery**,

```
SIZE = 10
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#youridher").bind('keyup', function() { 
            if($("#youridher").val().length <= SIZE && PHONE_REGEX) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }  
      });
});
```

Comment: This uses jQuery without mentioning it, and it does not check whether the characters are digits. And it does not work when data is pasted rather than typed.

Answer (score 0):

maxlength restrict the number of digits which cannot be more than the desired digits but it accepts less than the desired digits. If mobile No maxlength="10" it will not accept 11 but may accept anything upto 10

Answer (score 0):

Here all of the above outputs are giving a 10 digit number, but along with that the input field is accepting characters also, which is not the full solution. In order to set the 10 digit numbers only, we can use an input tag along with that type as number, and in that we can remove the up-down array by writing some small code in css which is shown below along with the input tag.

```
 <input name="phone" maxlength="10" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" class="form-control" id="mobile"  placeholder="Enter your phone Number" type="number">


input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply include parsley.js file in your document and in input element of mobile number enter this

***`data-parsley-type= "number" data-parsley-length="[10,10]" data-parsley-length-message= "Enter a Mobile Number"`***

you can change the message according to your requirement
you also need to initialize parsley.js file in your document by writing

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form').parsley();
        });
    </script>
```

---above code in your document.***

Comment: There is no jQuery in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below does the job as expected!

```
<input type="text" name="AUS" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="You can enter only 10 digits..." />


//type="text" <!-- always -->
//name="AUS" <!-- for Australia -->
//pattern="[0-9]{10}" <!-- 10 digits from 0 to 9 -->
//title="You can enter only 10 digits..." <!-- Pops a warning when input mismatches -->
```

Answer (score 0):

How to set a textbox format as 8 digit number(00000019)

```
string i = TextBox1.Text;
string Key = i.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0');
Response.Write(Key);
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to it. Thanks!

Comment: OP is "creating the input with JavaScript dynamically". This looks like an answer with server-side (C# ?) code; so I'm not sure this is what they had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="text" name='mobile_number' pattern=[0-9]{1}[0-9]{9}>
```

Comment: Code without any comments is a bad habit. Even in a question as simple as this. What if the OP is a newbie and does not know what is regex and cannot understand your code

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code if you want user to restrict with entering 10 digit in input control

```
<input class="form-control  input-md text-box single-line" id="ContactNumber" max="9999999999" min="1000000000" name="ContactNumber" required="required" type="number"  value="9876658688">
```

Benefits -

1. It will not allow to type any alphabets in input box because type of input box is 'number'
2. it will allow max 10 digits because max property is set to maximum possible value in 10 digits
3. it will not allow user to enter anything less than 10 digits as we want to restrict user in 10 digit phone number. min property in code is having minimum possible value in 10 digits so it will tell user to enter valid 10 digit value not less than that.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label for="name" class="form-label" style="width:50%;">Mobile No:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="mobile" pattern="\d{10}" title="Please enter exactly 10 digits" maxlength="10" required/></label>
```

This code will validate your contact form for non-numerical data entry. It will show an error message to the user when nonnumerical data is entered and fewer than 10 number is entered.

Comment: here max length is set to 10 only it will help the maximum length of the data.

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function() {

  original = document.getElementById("displayResult").value;

  if (original.length > 10) {
    lastCharRemove =
      original.slice(0, original.length - 1);
    document.getElementById('displayResult').value = lastCharRemove;

  }
}, 100);
```

```html
<input type="phone" placeholder="10 digit allowed" name="displayResult" id="displayResult" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {  
  $("#tax_no").keypress(function (e) {
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    if(length > 9) {
      return false;
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="nip_num" id="tax_no" />
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

maxLength property is not working for type="number".
You can use `<input type="tel" name="Mobile" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter user Mobile No." required />`. For me, it's working fine.

Comment: This is semantically incorrect and using pattern would be much better ! Checkout  the answers with pattern

Answer (score 0):

We can restrict it by using `Type : Number`

This input accepts only 10-digit numbers not any characters like the type text allows. If the number becomes greater than the length of the maxLength the input value will automatically take the first 10 numbers as input and restrict any following numbers.

```js
 const mobile = document.getElementById('mobile');
        mobile.addEventListener('input',function(event){
            const mobileValue = mobile.value;
            const maxValue = 10;
            if(mobileValue.length > maxValue){
                mobile.value = mobileValue.slice(0,10);
                console.log(mobileValue);
            }
        });
```

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="mobile" for="mobile">Mobile  :
<input type="number" pattern="[6-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" placeholder="enter your mobile number" id="mobile" name="mobile"  required >
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="tel" 
       id="phoneNumber"
       name="phoneNumber"
       pattern="[0-9]{10}"
       maxlength="10" required>
```

This will be helpful in HTML

Answer (score 0):

We can create event handlers and reusable functions to detect specific input fields based on the CSS classes assigned to them. This way, adding the `phone` class to a new input field is sufficient to apply our validation to it.

```js
/**
 * Sets up validation with an event listener for the provided input field.
 * Validation:
 * - Accepts only numbers (see regex: /\D/g)
 * - Truncates to a length of 10 characters
 * - Displays a warning if the phone number is less than 10 characters
 * - Adds a 'valid' attribute to the input field if it meets all the rules
 */
function checkInputPhoneValidation(element) {
  let phoneNumber = element.value.replace(/\D/g, ''); // Filter to numbers
  if (phoneNumber.length > 10) {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substr(0, 10); // Keep only the first 10 digits
  }
  element.value = phoneNumber;

  // Display warning if the phone number is less than 10 characters
  const warningElement = element.parentNode.querySelector('span.warning');
  if (phoneNumber.length < 10 && phoneNumber.length > 0) {
    if (!warningElement) {
      const warning = document.createElement('span');
      warning.textContent = 'The phone number should consist of 10 digits.';
      warning.style.color = 'red';
      warning.classList.add('warning');
      element.parentNode.appendChild(warning);
    }
    element.removeAttribute('valid'); // Remove 'valid' attribute if not meeting rules
    // or can use: element.setAttribute('valid', 'false');
  } else if (phoneNumber.length < 10 && element.hasAttribute('required') && element.getAttribute('required').toLowerCase() !== 'false') {
    element.removeAttribute('valid');
    // or can use: element.setAttribute('valid', 'false');
  } else {
    if (warningElement) {
      warningElement.remove();
    }
    element.setAttribute('valid', 'true'); // Add 'valid' attribute if meeting rules
  }
}

function addInputPhoneValidation(element) {
  element.addEventListener('input', function () {
    checkInputPhoneValidation(this);
  });
}

/**
 * Querying all input fields with the 'phone' class
 * and associating an event listener with each of them.
 */
const phoneElements = document.querySelectorAll('input.phone');
phoneElements.forEach((phoneElement) => {
  addInputPhoneValidation(phoneElement);
  // Perform initial validation without triggering the input event
  checkInputPhoneValidation(phoneElement);
});

/**
 * Function to log the 'phoneElements' to the console
 * - JUST DEBUG FUNCTION
 */
function logPhoneElements() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input.phone').forEach((e) => console.log(e, `- Valid? ${isValidInputPhone(e)}`));
}

/**
 * Function to check if the input phone field is valid
 * - The input element to check
 * - True if valid, false otherwise
 */
function isValidInputPhone(element) {
  if (element.hasAttribute('required') && element.getAttribute('required').toLowerCase() !== 'false') {
    return element.value.length === 10 && Boolean(element.getAttribute('valid'));
  } else {
    return Boolean(element.getAttribute('valid'));
  }
}

/**
 * Submit function that checks if all input phone fields are valid
 */
function submitForm() {
  const phoneElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input.phone')); // NodeList to Array
  let allValid = true;

  const hasNotValidInputPhone = phoneElements.find((element) => !isValidInputPhone(element));
  if (hasNotValidInputPhone !== undefined) {
    allValid = false;
  }

  if (allValid) {
    console.log('Request successfully sent!');
    // Here you can continue with the actual submission or perform other operations
  } else {
    console.log('Submit unsuccessful. Please ensure all fields are filled in correctly.');
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="logPhoneElements()">Display the HTML code of the input elements</button>

<div>
   <label>Required</label>
   <input type="text" class="phone" required />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Required</label>
  <input type="text" class="phone" required="true" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Optional</label>
  <input type="text" class="phone" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Optional</label>
  <input type="text" class="phone" required="false" />
</div>

<button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

By default, after the execution of the `forEach` and the initial check, the HTML code looks like this. Following this, due to the input event listeners, the validation is rerun on the respective input field with every keystroke.

```
<input type="text" class="phone" required></input> - Valid? false
<input type="text" class="phone" required="true"></input> - Valid? false
<input type="text" class="phone" valid="true"></input> - Valid? true
<input type="text" class="phone" required="false" valid="true"></input> - Valid? true
```